# Selector Specificity Not Overriding Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to override the **right** property for a h1 element that it is inheriting from the carousel-caption bootstrap class. It inherits right:15% and I am trying to set it to 0%. I found another post that led me to add id="bootstrap-overrides"to the  tag and then use the selector: #bootstrap-overrides h1.second but this still doesn't remove the property. I check also in the inspect element and this property is not crossed out. When I uncheck this property in the inspect element I am left with the behaviour I desire.

code from React component:

```
<div id="initialImage">
  <img src={logo} alt="Failed to load Image" class="img-fluid" />
  <div class="carousel-caption greeting">
    <h1 class="first">First.</h1>
    <h1 class="second">Second.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bootstrap-overrides h1.second {
  right: 0%;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Rock Salt", cursive;
  color: #fff2f4;
}
```

and as mentioned I have an id #bootstrap-overrides in the body tag of my index.html. Could it have something to do with the location of the import for boostrap?

Comment: Can you add code examples? Would be easier to see whats happening

Comment: I have updated the post now to include relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, are you adding `id="bootstrap-overrides"` directly to the h1?
If so, your css should look like this: `h1#bootstrap-overrides` otherwise, if you are applying it to the parent of h1, then try adding important to your css like so: `#bootstrap-overrides h1 { right: 0!important; }`

Comment: Is `!important` needed? Once you enter this area, there is no way back :)

Comment: @MrT Ordinarily, I'd recommend agains it, but prezo1 mentioned the code without it did not work. There are other ways of course, but I'd have to see the code in context to provide a "best practice" solution, though you are of course 100% correct, if you can avoid it, definitely do so :)

Comment: @VictorIvanov I have updated the post with the relevant code snippets. Please let me know if you see anything that I can change.